# Black Screen on pushViewController iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8

I am having a trouble with iOS 8. In a certain viewController, when I push another viewController, this last one instantiate correctly, passing in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc, but when it is presend, it show only a black screen. I am using xcode 6 Beta 6. In iOS 7 SDK is working fine.

The following code is how I am doing:

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *viewController = (MyViewController *)[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myController"];

[viewController setDelegate:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Could it be a bug from the new iOS or new SDK? Should I wait Apple fix this issue?

Thank you for attention and helping!

Comment: It appeared to be working fine for me if I present the view controller on iOS 7.0 with Xcode 6 Beta 6. I think, the issue might be something else.

Comment: Working fine for me, not sure why its black for you.

Comment: I now its weird, because I use this on many parts of my code. But in an especific view controller, it happens when I try to push new view controllers. Thank you.

Comment: I am having same problem when i tried dismiss model view controller for specific class

Comment: i'm having the same issue.. just a black screen, and then if I try and push a new view controller onto the nav I get an exception crash.. xcode beta 6, iOS 8 beta 5

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with pushViewController as well when running my app on iOS8 (while it was compiled in Xcode5).

It happened while I pushed a view controller (not animated) while my navigation controller was being transitioned. Pushing the view controller in the `init` method instead of the `viewDidLoad` solved the issue.

Comment: this is sort of what fixed it for me. I had a popover i was dismissing before pushing the new view controller. Having the popover dismiss entirely before pushing the new view controller did the trick. It seems to be an issue of doing two transitions at a time